# could not configure domains in zpanel vps

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, izpanel

I'm working on a vps server with zpanel.I really new in this area .I don't know how to set up WordPress and use it . I have gone through **[this manual](http://www.servermom.org/manually-install-wordpress-zpanel-vps/990/)**  .But this is not really helping . I got stuck at the 5th step.there is no ajax explorer in my zpanel.Then i gone through another manual which says to add a repo in zpanel .I don't know how to add that also .Can anyone please help me in setting up a wordpress site manualy into my zpanel.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1) first download some SSH client, I recommend Putty (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Choose the version that suits your operating system.

2) login to your VPS via SSH. In putty under "hostname your IP adress" put your VPS's IP or a domain name you have configured for that server. Check that the port number on the right to the hostname is 22. Click OPEN button in the bottom.

3) after providing your root username/password combo. follow all the steps from this page: http://www.servermom.org/install-ajaxplorer-file-manager-module-zpanel-cp/951/

> Step 1 – Login to your server as root. I assume you knew how to do
>   this.
>
> Step 2 – Then add additional repo for zPanel:
>
> shell> zppy repo add zppy.alineofcode.co.uk
>
> Step 3 – Now issue this command to update the repo:
>
> shell> zppy update
>
> Step 4 – Finally, here it is the main command to download and install
>   Ajaxplorer on your server:
>
> shell> zppy install ajaxplorer
>
> Step 5 – Open up your favorite web browser, visit the login page of
>   your zPanel server then login as zadmin.
>
> - login zpanel
>
> Step 6 – Go to Server Admin >> Module Admin menu.
>
> - enable ajaxplorer
>
> Step 7 – Next, enable Ajaxplorer module for Administrator, Reseller
>   and Client then hit the Save Changes button.
>
> - activate module
>
> Step 8 – Before you test it, you better do some necessary checks. Now
>   go to Putty / Terminal window again then issue this command;
>
> shell> nano /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd.conf
>
> Step 9 – Make sure the following line as below:
>
> "php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/zpanel/temp"
>
> and not as below (the wrong one):
>
> "php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /etc/zpanel/temp"
>
> Otherwise you might find some errors.
>
> Step 10 – Go back to zPanel configuration page in your browser. Click
>   on File Management menu >> then Ajaxplorer >> followed by clicking the
>   Launch Ajaxplorer button.
>
> - launch ajaxplorer
>
> Step 11 – You’ll notice that a new browser window appears launching
>   Ajaxplorer main UI up. Wait for few seconds till the interface fully
>   loaded.
>
> - loading
>
> And Voila!

4) back to your original instructions page and continue from step 5

Comment: I suggest you quote the content of the page. Links are prone to 404 oblivion. :)